# Python上で正規表現を使って文字列から時刻を抽出する方法

Tags: python, 正規表現

## したいこと

Python上で正規表現を使って、時刻と日本語が混ざった文字列から時刻を抽出したい。

## 現状

時刻の時間部分のみ抽出されて、全体が上手く取れない。

## コード

```
import re

time_str = '10:19発→11:50着1時間31分'
times = re.findall(r'([01][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]', time_str)
print(times)
```

## 現状の出力

`['10', '11']`

## 理想の出力

`['10:19', '11:50']`

## 環境

Python 3.8.2 (pyenv上）
macOS 11.6.1

正規表現・Stack Overflowともに初心者ですので不備がありましたらご指摘をお願いします。よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 3):

質問文にある例が想定通りに動いていないのは、カッコを使ってキャプチャしているグループが最初 2 桁の数字部分しか無いためです。

たとえば雑に次のように書けます。

```
import re

time_str = '10:19発→11:50着1時間31分'
times = re.search(r'([0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2})発→([0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2})着', time_str)
if times:
    print(times.groups())
```

なお、このままだとタプルが出力されますが、リストの方が良いのであれば `list(times.groups())` を使ってください。

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

time_str = '10:19発→11:50着1時間31分'
times = re.findall(r'((?:[01][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9])', time_str)
print(times)  # ['10:19', '11:50']
```

Answer (score 1):

[正規表現のシンタックス](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax)

> `(?:...)`
>
> 普通の丸括弧の、キャプチャしない版です。丸括弧で囲まれた正規表現にマッチしますが、このグループがマッチした部分文字列は、マッチを実行したあとで回収することも、そのパターン中で以降参照することも できません 。

```py
import re

time_str = '10:19発→11:50着1時間31分'
times = re.findall(r'((?:[01][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9])', time_str)
print(times)

#
['10:19', '11:50']
```